# Best way to combine first_name and last_name columns in Ruby on Rails 3?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a method in my `User` model:

```
def self.search(search)
  where('last_name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
end
```

However, it would be nice for my users to be able to search for both first_name and last_name within the same query.

I was thinking to create a `virtual attribute` like this:

```
def full_name
  [first_name, last_name].join(' ')
end
```

But is this efficient on a database level. Or is there a faster way to retrieve search results?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: There shouldn't be any database implication at all since the model is already loaded...

Answer (score 1):

Virtual attribute from your example is just class method and cannot be used by find-like ActiveRecord methods to query database.

Easiest way to retrive search result is modifying *Search* method:

```
def self.search(search)
  q = "%#{query}%"
  where("first_name + ' ' + last_name LIKE ? OR last_name + ' ' + first_name LIKE ?", [q, q])
end
```

where varchar concatenation syntax is compatible with your database of choice (MS SQL in my example).

Comment: Hey thanks, this works! But only if either a first_name OR a last_name is entered into the search form. If e.g. "John Doe" is entered, the record "John Doe" will not be retrieved. How can this be fixed?

Comment: I have combined my proposal with solution from ms-ati post. Now should works with "John Doe" and "Doe John".

Answer (score 0):

The search functionality, in your example, is still going to run at the SQL level.

So, to follow your example, your search code might be:

```
def self.search_full_name(query)
  q = "%#{query}%"
  where('last_name LIKE ? OR first_name LIKE ?', [q, q])
end
```

NOTE -- these sorts of LIKE queries, because they have a wildcard at the prefix, will be slow on large sets of data, even if they are indexed.

Comment: Works equally well. Thanks! But no record is retrieved when both first_name and last_name are being searched for.

Answer (score 0):

One way this can be implemented is by tokenizing (splitting) the search query and creating one where condition per each token:

```
  def self.search(query)
    conds  = []
    params = {}
    query.split.each_with_index do |token, index|
      conds.push "first_name LIKE :t#{index} OR last_name LIKE :t#{index}"
      params[:"t#{index}"] = "%#{token}%"
    end

    where(conds.join(" OR "), params)
  end
```

Also make sure you prevent SQL injection attacks.

However, it's better to use full-text searching tools, such as ElasticSearch and its Ruby gem named Tire to handle searches.

#### EDIT: Fixed the code.

Comment: Hello, looks promising but I am getting a syntax error and don't know how to fix it: `SQLite3::SQLException: near "%": syntax error: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "clients"  WHERE "clients"."user_id" = 1 AND (first_name LIKE %foo% OR last_name LIKE %foo%)`

Answer (score 0):

A scope can be made to handle complex modes, here's an example from one project I'm working on:

```
   scope :search_by_name, lambda { |q|
      if q
        case q
        when  /^(.+),\s*(.*?)$/
         where(["(last_name LIKE ? or maiden_name LIKE ?) AND (first_name LIKE ? OR common_name LIKE ? OR middle_name LIKE ?)",
           "%#{$1}%","%#{$1}%","%#{$2}%","%#{$2}%","%#{$2}%"
           ])
        when /^(.+)\s+(.*?)$/
          where(["(last_name LIKE ? or maiden_name LIKE ?) AND (first_name LIKE ? OR common_name LIKE ? OR middle_name LIKE ?)",
            "%#{$2}%","%#{$2}%","%#{$1}%","%#{$1}%","%#{$1}%"
            ])
        else
           where(["(last_name LIKE ? or maiden_name LIKE ? OR first_name LIKE ? OR common_name LIKE ? OR middle_name LIKE ?)",
             "%#{q}%","%#{q}%","%#{q}%","%#{q}%","%#{q}%"
             ])
        end
      else
       {}
      end
}
```

As you can see, I do a regex match to detect different patterns an build different searches depending on what is provided.  As an added bonus, if nothing is provided, it returns an empty hash which  effectively is `where(true)` and returns all results.

As mentioned elsewhere, the db cannot index the columns when a wildcard is used on both sides like `%foo%`, so this could potentially get slow on very large datasets.